# AVAudioPlayer play little bit on vibrate mode in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

i am develop app with avaudioplayer it's works perfectly, but,my problem is if my iPhone vibrate mode to open my app avaudioplayer plays audio little bit below seconds, i want to not play a avaudioplayer sound in vibrate mode.

here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
                                                                fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                                                 pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL]; 

    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops =-1;
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0.0f;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer Play]; 

}
```

can any one help me please..!

Thanks..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
```

As stated in the Apple Docs:

> **AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient**
>
> > For an app in which sound playback is nonprimary—that is, your app can be used successfully with the sound turned off.
> >     This category is also appropriate for “play along” style apps, such as a virtual piano that a user plays over iPod audio. When you use this category, audio from other apps mixes with your audio. Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch (called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone).

Should be what you're looking for specifically.

> Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch (called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone)